# Initializing captured-by-reference variable in C++ lambda?

Tags: c++, lambda

I have this C++ function object:

```
static unsigned long long const FNV_OFFSET_BASIS = 14695981039346656037ul;
static unsigned long long const FNV_PRIME        = 1099511628211ul;

struct fnv_hash {
    typedef unsigned long long value_type;

    fnv_hash( value_type *result ) {
        _result = result;
        *_result = FNV_OFFSET_BASIS;
    }

    void operator()( char c ) {  // Fowler–Noll–Vo FNV-1a hash function
        *_result ^= c;           //   see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fowler–Noll–Vo_hash_function
        *_result *= FNV_PRIME;
    }

private:
    value_type *_result;
};
```

that can be used like:

```
std::string const message = "hello, world";
hash::value_type hash_val;

std::for_each( message.begin(), message.end(), fnv_hash( &hash_val ) );
```

If I wanted to convert the function object to a lambda, there's the problem of initializing the captured variable `hash_val` to `FNV_OFFSET_BASIS` *only* when the underlying, compiler-generated lambda object is constructed. The only thing I can think of to do that is using yet another lambda:

```
std::for_each( message.begin(), message.end(),
    [&hv = [&hash_val]() -> decltype((hash_val)) {
               return hash_val = FNV_OFFSET_BASIS;  // Initialize and return reference to hash_val.
            }()                                     // Call the inner lambda.
           ]( char c ) {
        hv ^= c;
        hv *= FNV_PRIME;
    }
);
```

This works, but is there a cleaner way to to this?

---

**Note**: the example given is for pedagogical reasons only. The point of the question is how one can "initialize" a lambda in general --- and *not* how to solve this particular hash example.

**Note**: "It can't be done" is an acceptable answer.  I want *an* answer in the event someone asks me a question similar to: what are the case(s) where one ought to still use a function object as opposed to a lambda?

Comment: Since at this point the calling code needs to be aware of `FNV_OFFSET_BASIS` anyway, won't it be easiest to simply initialize `hash_val` before passing it to the lambda?

Comment: This sure looks like a job for `std::accumulate`...

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Easiest? Maybe. But I'd prefer code that _guarantees_ the user can't get it wrong.

Comment: @MooingDuck Feel free to swap out the example for some other example where the lambda requires some initial state. Whether I can use `std::accumulate` for _this_ particular example really isn't the point of the question.

Comment: Do you believe that making the user write that two-level lambda is an improvement? If correctness is your goal, why not just keep the named functional, `fnv_hash`? Since it's nicely encapsulated, it'd require some effort to misuse.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik No, the two-level lambda is horrible --- which is why I've posted the question in the first place: how to encapsulate the initialization somehow precisely so the user does _not_ have to write it (or at lease not write it in that convoluted way).

Comment: You say the fact you can use `std::accumulate` is only for this specific example, but I'm skeptical. The only real difference between `std::for_each` and `std::accumulate` is that `std::accumulate` makes state explicit, including handling initialization.  I think it is the solution in all cases.

Comment: @MooingDuck Maybe I'm being obtuse, but accumulate take a _binary_ operator whereas `fnv_hash` takes a unary operator. Anyway, if you're confidant, write the code as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say the fact you can use `std::accumulate` is only for this specific example, but I'm skeptical. The only real difference between `std::for_each` and `std::accumulate` is that `std::accumulate` makes state explicit, including handling initialization. I think it is the solution in all cases.

```
static unsigned long long const FNV_OFFSET_BASIS = 14695981039346656037ul;
static unsigned long long const FNV_PRIME        = 1099511628211ul;

struct fnv_hash {
    typedef unsigned long long value_type;
    value_type operator()(value_type _result, char c) {  // Fowler–Noll–Vo FNV-1a hash function
        _result ^= c;           //   see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fowler–Noll–Vo_hash_function
        _result *= FNV_PRIME;
        return _result;
    }
};

int main() {
std::string const message = "hello, world";
fnv_hash::value_type hash_val 
    = std::accumulate( message.begin(), message.end(), FNV_OFFSET_BASIS, fnv_hash() );
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0108d3fb96f1b7a0

`accumulate` takes a binary operator, but the first parameter is the entry in the container, and the second parameter is whatever state you need: in your case it's simply `value_type _result`. Though the concept extends to arbitrary state without issue.

Replacing this with a lambda is clearly trivial now:

```
value_type hash_val = std::accumulate( message.begin(), message.end(), FNV_OFFSET_BASIS, 
    [](value_type _result, char c) {  // Fowler–Noll–Vo FNV-1a hash function
        _result ^= c;           //   see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fowler–Noll–Vo_hash_function
        _result *= FNV_PRIME;
        return _result;
    });
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f9b78f8f21a2e0e

Comment: @PaulJ.Lucas: I just noticed that. Done.

Comment: I ran the lambda version against the original code and it doesn't produce the same result (though it's not obvious to me what's different).

Comment: @PaulJ.Lucas [The input parameters of both the functor and lambda are **backwards**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate), that is why the results are wrong. The parameters need to be `(value_type _result, char c)` not `(char c, value_type _result)`

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Whoopsie! :(

Answer (score 0):

At the cost of some efficiency, you could use a second, pass-by-value parameter to initialise `hash_val`:

```
std::for_each( message.begin(), message.end(),
    [&hash_val, initialised = false](char c) mutable {
        if (!initialised)
        {
            hash_val = FNV_OFFSET_BASIS;
            initialised = true;
        }
        hash_val ^= c;
        hash_val *= FNV_PRIME;
    }
);
```

But I prefer the functor.

Answer (score 0):

Simply initialize the `hash_val` variable at the point where it is declared, before the lambda captures it.  There is no need for the lambda to initialize it, only to mutate it, eg:

```cpp
using hash_value_type = unsigned long long;
static hash_value_type const FNV_OFFSET_BASIS = 14695981039346656037ul;
static hash_value_type const FNV_PRIME        = 1099511628211ul;

std::string const message = "hello, world";
hash_value_type hash_val = FNV_OFFSET_BASIS;

std::for_each(
    message.begin(), message.end(),
    [&hash_val](char c){
        hash_val ^= c;
        hash_val *= FNV_PRIME;
    }
);
```

Alternatively, use `std::accumulate()` instead of `std::for_each()`, then you don't even need to capture the `hash_val` variable at all, eg:

```cpp
using hash_value_type = unsigned long long;
static hash_value_type const FNV_OFFSET_BASIS = 14695981039346656037ul;
static hash_value_type const FNV_PRIME        = 1099511628211ul;

std::string const message = "hello, world";
hash_value_type hash_val = std::accumulate(
    message.begin(), message.end(),
    FNV_OFFSET_BASIS,
    [](hash_value_type val, char c) {
        val ^= c;
        val *= FNV_PRIME;
        return val;
    }
);
```